# Why that not get the total in python?

Tags: python

```
number=input('Enter  a number')
total=number*5
print(total)
```

This code is not print the total please help me.
This print only the number multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the number 5 times you got the code correct.
however I think you want to multiply the number by 5.
so convert the number in to integer. Then it will work.

You can check your type of variable by:

```
print(type(number))
```

---

Answer:-

```
number=input('Enter  a number')
number=int(number)
total=number*5
print(total)
```

or use in single statement.

```
number=int(input('Enter  a number'))
total=number*5
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you input a value, it will be saved as a `str` value. Instead, typecast the value into an integer using `int`. Note - when you multiply a string by an integer, it duplicates that value by the integer value.

```
>>> number=input('Enter  a number')
5
>>> print(type(number))
<class 'str'> 
>>> total=number*5
>>> print(total)
'55555'
```

Instead typecast the input using `int()`

```
>>> number=int(input('Enter  a number'))
5
>>> print(type(number))
<class 'int'> 
>>> total=number*5
>>> print(total)
15
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `input` function returns `str`.

It's exmplained in documentation: [Built-in functions: `input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

```
>>> num = input("enter a number: ")
enter a number: 13
>>> type(num)
<class 'str'>
```

You need to cast it to int by `int(num)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `input` returns a `string` you have to convert the `string` to `int`:

```
number = input('Enter a number')
total= int(number)*5
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get input from the user using `input()` it will save the varaible as a string by default. To remedy this you need to convert the string to int like this:

```
number = int(input('Enter  a number: '))
total = number * 5
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `input` returns a string. You need to cast it to `int` at somewhere. You can try this:

```
number = int(input('Enter  a number'))
total = number*5
print(total)
#Enter  a number 3
#15
```